# problems combining join with groupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, api, linq

I have following SQL request:

```
select cp.CategoryId, group_concat(cp.PathId order by cp.Level) as Path,
group_concat(c.Seo order by cp.Level) as SeoPath, max(cp.Level) as Level, 
max(c.SortOrder) as SortOrder from categorypaths cp
join categories c on cp.PathId = c.Id group by cp.CategoryId ORDER BY Level ASC
```

I can't translate a part of it. The part with `group_contact` exactly.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPath()
{
    using DataContext context = Context.CreateDbContext();

    var result = from cp in context.CategoryPaths
             join c in context.Categories
             on cp.PathId equals c.Id
             select new {cp.CategoryId, c.SortOrder };
                                
    return Ok(result);
}
```

I fail as soon I combine `join` with `groupBy`. If I print first `groupBy`, then I am out of scope and can't access previous date.

What may be a solution for that?

UPD:

I have these two tables
**Category**, where we have the basic information about its status and its namings (name to be displayed and SEO title)

[image: Category table]

And **CategoryPaths**, in which we contain information about the directory structure.

[image: Category Paths]

CategoryID - the category that is described
PathId is a category that is included in the path of the category selected by Id.
Level - the nesting level of the Path Id in the description of the path to the category we need

In this screenshot, for example, you can see that the full path for a category with ID 6 is `category 5 -> category 6`

I need to create LINQ request to get this table:

[image: Requested Table]

For getting this table, I've used this SQL request:

```
select cp.CategoryId, group_concat(cp.PathId order by cp.Level) as Path,
group_concat(c.Seo order by cp.Level) as SeoPath, max(cp.Level) as Level,
max(c.SortOrder) as SortOrder from categorypaths cp
join categories c on cp.PathId = c.Id group
by cp.CategoryId ORDER BY Level ASC
```

UPD FOR @SELVIN
I've tried to do that simple thing

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPath()
{
    using DataContext context = Context.CreateDbContext();

    var result = await context.CategoryPaths
                .GroupBy(cp => cp.CategoryId)
                .Select(table => new
                {
                    table.Key,
                    Path = string.Join(", ", table.OrderBy(a=> a.Level).Select(e => e.PathId))
                    //anotherGroupedPropInSimilarWay
                }).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

But as soon I run this, I get this:

`InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: c.CategoryId, ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: CategoryPath ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False .OrderBy(a => a.Level)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

But I use `.ToListAsync()` already. Don't get it

Comment: You might have better luck explaining in words (or interpretive dance) what you are trying to do, pasting actual minimal data, and the C# models, and explain the output you desire (leaving the sql for reference)

Comment: Got it! Give me few minutes!

Comment: Ill give you an upvote in advance

Comment: I don't think there is direct translation of group_concat in Entity Framework.

Comment: Check it, please

Comment: on client side it can be done with `GroupBy(...).Select(g=>new { g.Key, string.Join(", ", g.OrderBy(...).Select(e=>e.Prop)), anotherGroupedPropInSimilarWay } )` ... but as Evk wrote EF  cannot translate this to SQL

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and reply to you as soon as possible!

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: No way with pure EF Core, third party extensions may help to generate such SQL.

Comment: materialize first: `var tempResults = await context.CategoryPaths.GroupBy(cp => cp.CategoryId)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    CategoryId = g.Key,
                    Rows = await g.Select(i => new { i.PathId, i.Level }).AsAsyncEnumerable()
                }).AsAsyncEnumerable();`  then use string join `var result = tempResults.Select(i =>new  { i.CategoryId  
 Path = string.Join(", ", i.Rows.OrderBy(r=> r.Level).Select(r => r.PathId)) }).ToList();`

Comment: I really hope this will work, but the compiler won't let me run the code. Swears at the first mention .AsAsyncEnumerable(). There is just .AsEnumerable(), but then there are even more errors. Here is the screenshot: https://skr.sh/sAiThe6VMsg and the error code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061